# how to work with list of variables in makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a list of variables:

```
VAR_LIST= var1 var2 var3 var4 var5
```

and a script (`var_process.py`)in recipe that uses the variable as one of the option.

How do i create a recurring instance that would sequentially process the `var_process.py` using `VAR_LIST`.

I have the makefile setup like this, but i cant figure out how can i setup `VAR_LIST` to be sequential.

```
target1: $(foreach var, $(VAR_LIST), $(var)_process_var.txt)

 %_process_var.txt:var_process.py %_var.txt
     python $< -i $(word 2, $^) -var VAR_LIST -o $@
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't it work to use `$*`?  I would write it like this:

```
%_process_var.txt: var_process.py %_var.txt
        python $< -i $(word 2, $^) -var $* -o $@
```

Comment: yes it worked..thanks a bunch...forgot about the $* :)